# How do I set the default admin page theme to light theme in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am just now trying Wagtail for a project in my company, in Wagtail 5, the dark theme is introduced and became the default theme for the wagtail admin page, this is great for me but I was told that the client wanted it to be light theme.

I know that we could set the theme preference from the Account page, but is there a way to make the light theme as the default? the default light theme is already satisfactory so I wonder how do I set it.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the : wagtail.users.models

```
class AdminThemes(models.TextChoices):
    SYSTEM = "system", _("System default")
    LIGHT = "light", _("Light")
    DARK = "dark", _("Dark")

theme = models.CharField(
    verbose_name=_("admin theme"),
    choices=AdminThemes.choices,
    default=AdminThemes.LIGHT,
    max_length=40,
)
```

but you still need to hit the "account" setting to refresh the user admin to light